# How to copy the content of the source block at point to the kill ring?

Tags: org-babel

Suppose you're in org mode and working with source code.

Your point is currently inside a source block at some random position.

Is there an easy way to copy the body of source block (excluding `#+begin_src <header args>` and `#+end_src`)?

I was thinking of an automated, quick solution, like using a function.

The manual way for me to do this is to use `mark-paragraph` and then `kill-ring-save`.

But the latter unfortunately includes the last line of the source block, the #+end_src line.

I've played around with universal arguments -1 before `mark-paragraph`, but I couldn't manage to exclude the last line (`#+end_src`).

Comment: Welcome! What version of emacs and version of org-mode are you using? The answer(s) might change depending on the versions. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't post an answer in the question. Post it as an answer. (You can accept your own answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLUTION:

```
(defun kill-src-block-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (kill-new (plist-get (cadr (org-element-at-point)) :value))
  )
```

Comment: You should be able to accept your answer by now (just check the tick mark to the left of it). If there is a good answer, it's a good idea to accept it: it "closes" the question, allowing future visitors to see that the question has indeed been answered.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the body of the code block as a string by executing the following with `point` in the source block:

```el
(plist-get (cadr (org-element-at-point)) :value)
```

You can also expand the body of a source block with `C-c C-v C-v` (bound to `org-babel-expand-src-block`) which creates a preview buffer with not only the source code but also the surrounding context (e.g. information coming from the headers of the source block).

Comment: Thank you. Your solution returns a string, not a region that I can pass to kill-ring-save, so I instead used kill-new, but it works just as good, IMHO. I added the answer below by replying to my question.

Answer (score 0):

As of Org 9.7, the existing answers do not work anymore due to [some changes in the org-element API](https://list.orgmode.org/orgmode/874jnudps5.fsf@localhost/) that introduce deferred parsed values.

This solution uses `org-element-property`, which takes care of deferred properties.  See [Org Element API](https://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-element-api.html).

```lisp
(defun kill-src-block-at-point ()
 (interactive)
 (kill-new (org-element-property :value (org-element-at-point))))
```